# What is the equivalent to "event.target.value" in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s2ujmr?file=src/app/pages/home/home.component.html

I'm trying to make the dropdown menu work for filtering the flags you see underneath it.

---

I thought I could implement something similar to what I did for the search bar filtering method, like:

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private api: ApiService){}

  regionOptions = ['Africa', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];

  countries!: Country[];
  displayCountries?: Country[];

  destroy$ = new Subject<void>()
  countryControl = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getAllCountries().subscribe((response: Country[]) => {
      this.countries = response;
      this.displayCountries = response;
    });

    this.countryControl.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$),debounceTime(100)).subscribe((value: string) => this.updateDisplayCountries(value))
  }

  //SEARCH BAR
  private updateDisplayCountries(searchTerm: string): void {
    this.displayCountries = this.countries.filter((country: Country ) => this.isCountrySearched(country, searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
  }
  private isCountrySearched(country: any, searchTerm: string): boolean {
    return country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || country.name.official.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  }
  
  //DROPDOWN  <-------------------------------------------THIS PART
  private updateDisplayRegions(region: string): void {
    this.displayCountries = this.countries.filter((country: Country ) => this.isRegionFiltered(country, region.toLowerCase()))
  }
  private isRegionFiltered(country: any, selectedRegion: string): boolean {
    return country.region.toLowerCase().includes(selectedRegion)
  }

  

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

and then in the HTML add a "(change)" event listener like this:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="drop-down">
  <select (change)="updateDisplayRegions($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let region of regionOptions" value="{{region}}">{{region}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

but for this to work (which idk if it's even how you do this or if it would actually work) I need to pass in the dropdown selection value to the function. I'm used to using "event.target.value" in other frameworks, but in Angular I'm getting the errors:

> Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)
>
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)

---

How do I pass the value of the dropdown selection into the change function so it can go ahead and filter? What does angular use instead of "event.target.value"?

Am I approaching this completely wrong?

Comment: `updateDisplayRegions` method should be public because you are binding it to template, otherwise it will fail in compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass value via reference as shown below.

```
<div class="drop-down">
  <select #regionRef (change)="updateDisplayRegions(regionRef.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let region of regionOptions" value="{{region}}">{{region}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! So the key here is "#regionRef"? What is this called so I can learn more about it? Is it called "template refs"? "Template binding"? What should I look up in the docs?

Comment: Also, not a big deal, but it doesn't work alongside the search bar. Is there anyway to implement both the searchbar and the dropdown menu? So you could select "Europe" and then the search bar will only be searching Europe?

Comment: This is called template reference variable. You can read more about it here at https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables